# How to mock Logger in Rails test using Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocking, functional-testing

In test_helper:

```
class Logger
    @@log = []

  def self.info(message)
    @@log.push(message)
  end

  def self.log
    @@log
  end
end
```

But when running the tests it seems to use the regular Logger.

How to create a mock for the Logger?

Rails 3.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your logger to the Rails.logger for Rails to use it... For you to fully implement logger, you need to implement all of the methods http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html (namely #debug, #warn, #error, #fatal)

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")

class Logger
    @@log = []

  def self.info(message)
    @@log.push(message)
  end 

  def self.log
    @@log
  end 
end


class TestLogCase < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Rails.logger = Logger
  end 

  test "records the log" do
    Rails.logger.info "My Message"
    assert_true Logger.log.include?("My Message")
  end                                                                                                                         
end
```

Comment: I think `assert_true Logger.log.include?` needs to be `assert_true Rails.logger.log.include?`?

Comment: OK, that helps. But it is not calling the new Logger from within my test. It seems to be calling the `Rails.logger`.

Comment: @BSeven 1) Yes, you're correct on the assertion. 2) But this logger becomes the Rails.logger. So it should use your logger.

Comment: @BSeven Actually, I like it the way it is. You can implement however you want, obvs, but I like checking that sending to Rails.logger will be including in your #log

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest a better strategy is to mock the rails logger using mocha

```
class TestLogCase < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  require 'mocha/mini_test'

  test "records the log" do
    Rails.logger.expects(:info).with('My message')
    Rails.logger.info "My Message"
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mocha

```
  before do
    logger = mock
    MyModel.any_instance.stubs(:logger).returns(logger)
    logger.stubs(:debug).returns(true)
  end
```